# What's $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR''] in node.js?

Tags: node.js

How to get the IP address of the machine where the node.js server is running? I've checked process.env. But that doesn't seem to include this variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `net.createServer()` server has an [`.address()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html#server.address) property.